# Category with product by vendor - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a Laravel with MySQL e-commerce like website, and I can show all the products under its categories by vendor/store.

But the problem is, if I added a product under the same category, it also shows to other vendor which also have that category, that shouldn't have happen.

My Query:

```
$categories = Categories::with('products')
    ->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('store_id' ,$id);
})
->get();
```

I think the problem is in the `with` part? but I don't know exactly how to do it.

DB Structure:

```
store

id  |  name


products

id | store_id  | category_id | name


categories
id | name
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Lewis, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WhereHas()` check if it has it, but does not filter the result. Does it have a product with this store, if yes return all categories where you now includes products that does not filter.

There is an array syntax, for filtering `with()` call. This will show the products correctly.

```
Categories::with(['products' => function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('store_id' ,$id);
}])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer mrhn, i will try this and update you asap.

Comment: i added use ($id) to your answer. now it's working as expected! Thanks a lot @mrhn

Comment: ofc, went a little quick :)